# Delete a node from the binary tree with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

By making a node to be deleted from the tree, the node (case 1) can be a node with a single arm (right or left), or a node with both branches. In case the node to be deleted is an intermediate node with two branches, there are 2 different methods.
Method 1: the largest knot on the left arm or the smallest knot on the right arm, and
Method 2: The node in the branch with more depth (or the number of elements) is fulfilled so that the right or left arm is balanced.
Both methods have to be coded with separate functions.

How can I do these two methods?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left   = None
        self.right  = None
        self.parent = None  # new
        self.data   = data
    def insert(self, data):
        if self.data:                       # add by comparison
            if data < self.data:            # left if small     
                if self.left is None:           # add left if left is blank
                    self.left = Node(data)
                    self.left.parent = self     # new
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)      # if left is not empty add to left sub-tree
            elif data > self.data:          # right if greater
                if self.right is None:          # add right if right is blank
                    self.right = Node(data)
                    self.right.parent = self    # new
                else:                           # if right is not empty add to sub-tree right
                    self.right.insert(data)
            else:
                self.data = data        # the first dream of the tree
        
    # print Tree
    def PrintTree(self):
        print( self.data,end='-')
        if self.left:
            self.left.PrintTree()
        if self.right:
            self.right.PrintTree()
    
    def sizeTree(self): 
        if self.left and self.right:
            return 1 + self.left.sizeTree() + self.right.sizeTree()
        elif self.left:
            return 1 + self.left.sizeTree()
        elif self.right:
            return 1 + self.right.sizeTree()
        else:
            return 1

    def depth(self):
        if self.left and self.right:
            l = self.left.depth()
            r = self.right.depth()
            return 1 + max(l,r)
        elif self.left:
            return 1 + self.left.depth()
        elif self.right:
            return 1 + self.right.depth()
        else:
            return 1

# Use the insert method to add nodes

root = Node(25)
root.insert(12)
root.insert(10)
root.insert(22)
root.insert(5)
root.insert(36)
root.insert(30)
root.insert(40)
root.insert(28)
root.insert(38)
root.insert(48)
root.PrintTree()


"""
# 25,36,20,10,5,22,40,48,38,30,22,12,28
root = Node(25)
root.insert(36)
root.insert(20)
root.insert(10)
root.insert(5)
root.insert(22)
root.insert(40)
root.insert(48)
root.insert(38)
root.insert(30)
root.insert(12)
root.insert(28)
print("\n",root.sizeTree(),root.depth())
"""
```

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: @mkrieger1Could you give an idea exactly how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago I was playing with this and came up with this code:

```
def search(self, value):
    """
    Recursively looks to the left and right of Tree depending on the provided value
    and returns it if it is present within Tree.

    Args:
        value (int): value to be searched for within Tree

    Returns:
        value if value exists in Tree otherwise None
    """
    if value < self.data:
        if self.left is None:
            return None
        return self.left.search(value)
    elif value > self.data:
        if self.right is None:
            return None
        return self.right.search(value)
    else:
        return self.data

def _findNodeToDelete(self, value, previous=None):
    """
    Recursively looks to the left and right of Tree depending on the provided value
    and returns it if it is present within Tree.

    Args:
        value (int): value to be searched for within Tree

    Returns:
        value if value exists in Tree otherwise None
    """
    if value < self.data:
        if self.left is None:
            return None
        return self.left._findNodeToDelete(value, self)
    elif value > self.data:
        if self.right is None:
            return None
        return self.right._findNodeToDelete(value, self)
    else:
        return self, previous
    
def _mergeNodes(self, target):
    self.data = target.data
    self.left = target.left
    self.right = target.right
    
def deleteNode(self, value, start=None):
    
    if self.search(value):
    
        to_delete, parent = self._findNodeToDelete(value, start)
        
        if to_delete.right and to_delete.left:
            new_value = to_delete.right.min
            to_delete.data = new_value
            to_delete.right.deleteNode(new_value, to_delete)
        
        elif to_delete.left:
            to_delete._mergeNodes(to_delete.left)
            
        elif to_delete.right:
            to_delete._mergeNodes(to_delete.right)
            
        else:
            if parent:
                if parent.data > value:
                    parent.left = None
                else:
                    parent.right = None
            else:
                self.data = None
```

Note, I don't use `parent` attribute, rather calculate it while deleting.